# Upload Apache POI XLSX generated files to CodeIgniter website

Tags: java, php, codeigniter, apache-poi

I have to upload XLSX files to a web application. This web application uses CodeIgniter to check and import those files.

Furthermore, I have to generate these XLSX files from another one. In order to read and write XLSX files, I use Apache Poi. This part is pretty easy and works well.

But, here is my problem: when uploading an auto-generated file, CodeIgniter decline the files saying that this file type is not allowed. It's probably a missing property that's not created by Apache POI library but I didn't managed to find which one.

Another 'fun' fact is that when opening an Apache Poi auto-generated file with Microsoft Excel then saving it without any modification the file gains something like 3Ko of data and becomes valid for CodeIgniter. It doesn't work with LibreOffice Calc which apparently adds some data but not the same as Microsoft Excel do.

Do you have any idea of which property or data could be missing? Any method to resolve my problem?

---

Edit: after some more investigations and according to php [finfo_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php) function (used by CodeIgniter) my bad file has following mime type `application/octet-stream` while a legit file has following mime type `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`. Then, I think that Apache Poi has some bug when generating XLSX.

---

Edit 2: Finally, there's 2 XLSX type (see enclosed screenshot). Only the second one is recognized as an `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet` by `finfo_file`. Unfortunately, Apache Poi generates signature of the first type. Thus, it isn't recognized as a XLSX.
[image]

Comment: Report a bug to CodeIgniter?

Comment: It could be a solution. But CodeIgniter uses [fileinfo_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php) function to determine which mime type the file has. As far as I know, this is a very used and trustable library.

Comment: Try calling that standalone to check? And if that gets it wrong, report a bug in that!

Comment: Just tried that and it effectively get an "application/octet-stream" mime type. I'll report a bug! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This strange behaviour finally comes from the ambiguity of the XLSX file format. It covers two different file formats (as you can see on the enclosed picture from https://www.filesignatures.net/). Only the second one is recognized as an `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet` by `finfo_file` whereas Apache Poi generates files of the first type. Thus, the upload fails saying the file type is not allowed.

[image]

Comment: You can't reliably detect OOXML file types (eg xlsx) from the first few bytes alone, you need to look inside the zip structure and check the `[Content_Types].xml` file. See https://github.com/apache/tika/blob/master/tika-parsers/src/main/java/org/apache/tika/parser/pkg/ZipContainerDetector.java for an idea of the work involved in detecting zip-based file types properly!